# buffer overflow task, cannot run shellcode

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I have been struggling for 1 week and cannot figure this out. Please help.
My friend gave me an executable which is just a simple server and has buffer overflow vulnerability. My goal is to get a reverse/bind shell.
I followed instruction from:
https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/07/19/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-1-stack-based-overflows/
and was able to find "jmp esp" and successfully run shellcode from:
https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/102847/All-Windows-Null-Free-CreateProcessA-Calc-Shellcode.html
The problem is I am not able to run any shellcode from metasploit/internet. 
and I tried to modify shellcode, was able to pop notepad, but cannot run command like:

1. msconfig
2. echo test>test.txt
3. cmd /c calc

below is my shellcode:

```
"\x31\xdb\x64\x8b\x7b\x30\x8b\x7f"
    "\x0c\x8b\x7f\x1c\x8b\x47\x08\x8b"
    "\x77\x20\x8b\x3f\x80\x7e\x0c\x33"
    "\x75\xf2\x89\xc7\x03\x78\x3c\x8b"
    "\x57\x78\x01\xc2\x8b\x7a\x20\x01"
    "\xc7\x89\xdd\x8b\x34\xaf\x01\xc6"
    "\x45\x81\x3e\x43\x72\x65\x61\x75"
    "\xf2\x81\x7e\x08\x6f\x63\x65\x73"
    "\x75\xe9\x8b\x7a\x24\x01\xc7\x66"
    "\x8b\x2c\x6f\x8b\x7a\x1c\x01\xc7"
    "\x8b\x7c\xaf\xfc\x01\xc7\x89\xd9"
    "\xb1\xff\x53\xe2\xfd"
    #"\x68\x63\x61\x6c\x63" #calc
    #
    "\x68\x70\x61\x64\x20\x68\x6E\x6F\x74\x65"#notepad

    #"\x68\x6E\x66\x69\x67\x68\x6D\x73\x63\x6F"#msconfig
    "\x89\xe2\x52\x52\x53\x53"
    "\x53\x53\x53\x53\x52\x53\xff\xd7"
```

please give me some hint about why I cannot run any other shellcode and command.

Environment: win 7 professional, Macfee installed, Immunity Debugger

I suspect that he used some protection mechanism when compiling the executable. But since I can pop calc and notepad, why I cannot run other command?
Anyway, I am new to buffer overflow and shellcode, please help.
----------------------update------------------------
Asked some people, they said I should try to turn off some protection. I tried disabling DEP, but still not work. should I disable ASLR and UAC?

Comment: This is not enough information to solve your problem. Try single stepping through each instruction of your shellcode and focus on checking the arguments just before each system call as well as the return value after each. Then you can at least see WHERE in your shellcode you're having problems.

Comment: Also, no, if calc shellcode works then ASLR/DEP should not cause you any problems unless the shellcode is very very poorly written and not actually self-contained position independent code (PIC) as shellcode should be